# I'm facing the error Stream.Length throws NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream, httpwebresponse, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am trying to POST some data from ASP.Net application to PHP using `HttpWebRequest` object. But when I try reading the `Request` content using

```
Stream myStream = myWebReq.GetRequestStream();
```

I am getting an error

> 'responseStream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'.
>   Length = 'dataStream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
>   Position = 'dataStream.Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Here is the code

```
string strURL = null;
HttpWebRequest myWebReq = default(HttpWebRequest);
HttpWebResponse myWebResp = default(HttpWebResponse);

byte[] byteData = null;
StreamReader sr = default(StreamReader);
strURL = "http://people.com.pk/nppm/hrms_ppm_service.php?dump=1";
myWebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);
myWebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
myWebReq.Method = "POST";

Label1.Text = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(batches).ToString();

byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Label1.Text);
myWebReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

myWebReq.KeepAlive = true;

if (myWebReq.Proxy != null)
{
   myWebReq.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
}

Stream myStream = myWebReq.GetRequestStream();

if (byteData.Length > 0)
{
   myStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
   myStream.Close();
}

myWebResp = (HttpWebResponse)myWebReq.GetResponse();
sr = new StreamReader(myWebResp.GetResponseStream());
string strJSON__2 = sr.ReadToEnd();
Label1.Text = strJSON__2;
```

Comment: can you post the complete stack trace of excpetion that is in which line it threw excpetion....

Comment: excpetion is here...Stream myStream = myWebReq.GetRequestStream();          <blink>
    Length = 'dataStream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

    Position = 'dataStream.Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
    </blink>

Answer (score 0):

Just check your `HttpWebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy` property.
As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) suggest that **HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream** method will throw `NotSupportedException` only when the request cache validator indicates that the response for the request can be served from the cache; however, requests that write data must not use the cache. This exception can occur if you are using a custom cache validator that is incorrectly implemented.

Comment: have clear the cache with following lines...HttpWebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore); still problem is  "NotSupportedException"

Comment: Try this,  myWebReq.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache); //RequestCacheLevel should be BypassCache

Comment: @devanalysts I pasted your code, this works fine on my machine

Comment: i have tried with 2 machines, but still Exception is "Stream.Length throws NotSupportedException".

Comment: @devanalysts you said error is here Stream myStream = myWebReq.GetRequestStream(), but in your stack trace posted in question 'responseStream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'????? something you are not pasting in question correctely....